# Clean project in Android Studio

Tags: android, project, android-studio, code-cleanup

When I started to develop android project in Android Studio, I noticed that there is no

> Clean project

section.
So I tried to `gradlew clean` command in the terminal embedded to Android Studio.

But I got this error: `JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory`

I don't understand, should I also set a gradle path to clean it?

[image: view from Android Studio embedded DOS terminal]

---

I changed the path and remove the double slash but I still get the same error

[image]

Comment: You can not have double slash in directory path in Windows (hint: "C:\java\jdk-7-40**\\**bin"). Also, make sure that such a path really exists on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I just checked the system variables, and I reliased that I missed to not putting more slash into **user variables** as in **system variables**

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the picture your JAVA_HOME variable is pointing to the bin directory. Please remove the bin it should point the root directory of your jdk

it should look like

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **JAVA_HOME enviroment variable**.

Comment: What I want to know is actually where to set the JAVA path, more. Because I have already set the JAVA_HOME as in the pic > C:\java\jdk-7-40\

Answer (score 0):

Either fix your **JAVA_HOME** environment or update to the latest version of Android Studio. I believe that they already removed the hassle of setting complicated things like that.

[Simple tutorial on how to set the JAVA_HOME variable.](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/setting-java-home-variable-in-windows/)

Comment: I have already set the JAVA_HOME as you see in the pic as:   C:\java\jdk-7-40\